# Android Eclipse XML editor hides XML

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, editor

I have absolutely now idea how this happened. For some reason the tabs under the editor doesn't show up, so I can't edit the XML text, I'm stuck with drag and drop interface.

Here's a screenshot, notice the absence of the tabs like in http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html

Any ideas that don't involve re-installing Eclipse? Nothing in error log, running ADT v22.0.1-685705

[image]

Comment: Just in case, did you try restarting eclipse?

Comment: yes i did. i'm playing with Customize Perspective now as I think it's a likely candidate

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's happening, but you could also try

```
Right click xml file => Open With => Android Common XML Editor
```

**EDIT**

As a workaround, you could try the keyboard shortcuts to switch between both views

```
Alt + F7
```

and

```
Alt + Shift + F7
```

Comment: it's been set to that since the start

Comment: Posted a possible workaround. Won't make the tabs appear, but at least you should be able to switch both edit modes till you find a solution.

Comment: didn't work... i'm going to use this opportunity to give Android Studio a chance. thank you for taking the time to answer though

Comment: Well, sorry not being of more helpful. Best of lucks!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the Eclipse Dark Juno theme I was using was hiding the tabs. Changing back to default did it for me.